# MySQL: Weird behavior in querying multiple tables

Tags: mysql

I know this is supposed to work, I've done it hundreds of times before but somehow tonight (or morning, depending on where you are) it is not doing what it is supposed to do.

I am trying to query multiple tables, however I encountered some difficulties so I reduced to query to the max:

```
SELECT tasks.* FROM tasks, assigned WHERE tasks.id = 1 //not working
SELECT * FROM tasks WHERE id = 1 //working
```

I tried quoting them but with no success. Now, what is wrong with the first statement?

Comment: do you get a syntax error? or just results you do not expect?

Comment: What isn't working? Having no join condition, you should get the number of rows tasks.id = 1 multiplied by the total rows in assigned.

Comment: @Randy "MySQL returned an empty result set" is what I get

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski in the second statement I get one result (there is only one task with id 1) and in the first statement I get an empty set

Comment: are there any rows in the table 'assigned'?

Comment: @Andrew If there are no rows in `assigned` then, you'll get nothing back. You have no joining condition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using an implicit join syntax. With that, you need someway to join those tables, which you are missing:

```
SELECT tasks.*
FROM tasks, assigned
WHERE tasks.id = assigned.task # <-- missing this
    AND tasks.id = 1
```

You should practice using explicit `JOIN` syntax (ANSI standard):

```
SELECT tasks.col1
FROM tasks
JOIN assigned ON assigned.task = tasks.id
WHERE tasks.id = 1
```

If you're not selecting anything from `assigned`, why fetch that result set?

Also, you should use a column list rather than using `SELECT *`.

**Update**

If there are records in `tasks` but not in `assigned` at the time, you can use a `LEFT JOIN` which will return the records in `tasks` even if there are no records in `assigned`.

```
SELECT tasks.col1
FROM tasks
LEFT JOIN assigned ON assigned.task = tasks.id
WHERE tasks.id = 1
```

Comment: what if there isn't any data related to my `tasks.id` at the moment of querying? Does it mean the query will result in an empty set?

Comment: @Andrew Then you should use a `LEFT JOIN`, which will allow an empty set to be joined. See my update.